# Problemas ao persistir dados no Doctrine

Tags: php, mvc, doctrine

Estou a fazer isto:

```
  function Autenticar($objecto) {

        //require $this->db;
        require ROOT . "config/bootstrap.php";

        return $entityManager->getRepository('models\Usuarios')->findOneBy(array('login' => $objecto->login, 'senha' => $objecto->senha));
    }
```

Ele me retorna isto:

> Class "models\Usuarios" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

Alguém tem uma ideia do que esta a se passar?

Já lutei aqui e não consegui nada.

Comment: O repositório retorna um, ou uma coleção de entidades. Você está definindo que essa entidade é `models\Usuarios`, é isso mesmo?

Comment: esse é o caminho onde esta a minha classe mapeada. o caminho é models\usuarios (models e o nome do meu namespace)

Comment: Você tem que passar o caminho completo da classe. Se você tem uma classe `Usuario` dentro do namespace `Models\Usuarios`, então tem que usar `Models\Usuarios\Usuario`. E se atente às maiúsculas também.

Comment: ok, obrigado era mesmo isso! valeuu

Answer (score 1):

Mudei a configuração da criação entity manager desse jeito

setando as configurações definidas anteriormente

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($entidades, $isDevMode, NULL, NULL, FALSE); //adicionei Null no 3 e 4 parametro, e no 5 parametro coloquei true pra ele aceitar  uso de NAMESPACE..
```

criando o Entity Manager com base nas configurações de dev e banco de dados

```
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

Ok Valeu pela ajuda